# Is there a way to reload subgit configuration after import has started?

Tags: subgit

I have a large repository (20000+ commits) that takes a while to do a one-time cutover from SVN to git. There is a tangled web of hundreds of branches, some of which are proper branches, others are more like developer sandboxes, some are partial branches, some are tags, some are unrelated repos which I will be extricating, etc. so I am familiar with the subgit configure feature and modified the config file in the subgit directory.

These branches create a lot of errors from subgit (I don't know why for most of them), and while I don't care about individual branches/errors, I don't want to exclude them all. There was an explosion of creating these branches around the 10000th commit, so I have to wade through the first half of the repo before any of these errors come up (about 4 hours).

So I'm wondering: **Is there a way to restart the import after an error with a modified config file?** It could either comb back through the commits it already did and make sure they look good or start at the problematic one, either way it would ideally succeed because I changed the branch mapping to exclude the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to restart the initial import with the same command used for the initial start, but the thing is that the mapping configuration change that affects branches mapping (means adds or removes branches to/from the configuration) requires the repository import restart from scratch as such the configuration changes usually affect the resulting Git objects.